# LINQ to SQL lambda where [nullable object must have a value error]

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, lambda

I'm getting the error

> [nullable object must have a value]

And it's point at the following part of the code

```
.Min(x => x.Time)
```

Here's the whole function.

```
public DateTime GetFirstRecord(long userId)
        {
            DateTime firstRecordDate;

            using (DeviceExerciseDataDataContext context = new DeviceExerciseDataDataContext())
            {
                firstRecordDate = (DateTime)context.Datas.Where(x => x.UserID.Equals(userId)).Min(x => x.Time);
            }

            return firstRecordDate;
        }
```

**Also, how can I debug this functions lambda?  When I hover over the x's, It shows no value.  When when I try to print in the immediate window, it says "the name 'x' does not exist in the current context"**

**Edit:**

```
So I've updated my code to this:

public DateTime? GetFirstRecord(long userId)
        {
            DateTime? firstRecordDate;
            firstRecordDate = DateTime.Now;

            using (DeviceExerciseDataDataContext context = new DeviceExerciseDataDataContext())
            {
                var test = context.Datas.Where(x => x.UserID.Equals(userId));
                if (test != null)
                    firstRecordDate = (DateTime)test.Min(x => x.Time);
                else
                    firstRecordDate = null;   
            }

            return firstRecordDate;
        }
```

But I'm still getting the save error.

In the DB, There are no null value's **anywhere**.  Oh, and it doesn't go to the else, in the if/else block.

Comment: To debug a lambda, you can put a breakpoint on the lambda itself, to do this have your cursor inside the lambda and hit [F9] and the breakpoint will be in the lambda instead of the whole line.

Comment: There's no point in testing `test != null`, since `test` will just be the iterator returned from the `Where()` clause, and certainly won't be `null`. Can you show us the model? Is `x.Time` a `DateTime` or a `Nullable<DateTime>`? What is the value of `test.Count()`?

Comment: @James Michael Hare: Wont work with Linq2SQL, unless you force it to list first.

Comment: Good to know on Linq2SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good chance that context.Datas could be null or any of the Data's userId could be null or x.Time is null and you are trying to cast it as (DateTime) instead of (DateTime?).

You will have to add conditions to capture these null values in your assignment statement something like:

```
DateTime? datevalue = context.Datas == null
    ? null
    : (DateTime?)context.Datas.Where(x => x.UserId != null && x.UserID.Equals(userId))
                              .Min(x => x.Time);
```

Comment: Nice catch!  I forgot the casting of DateTime needed the question mark as well.  Thanks everyone!  +1 for everyone! lol.  Since I'm pretty much using everyone's idea.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible for firstRecordDate to be null, the .Min isn't allowed.

Can you try this?

```
firstRecordDate = (DateTime)context.Datas.Where(x => x.UserID.Equals(userId));
if (firstRecordDate.Count() > 0) firstRecordDate = firstRecordDate.Min(x => x.Time);
```

if that works, then that's your problem.  There are probably more elegant ways to deal with this but at least you will have a workaround to start with.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried what you posted, but I'm still getting the same error.  Please see above as I've posted my newly updated code.

Answer (score 2):

If you can be assured that at least one row has a valid time you could filter out the entries that have `null` as Time (or handle the case that `DateTime.MaxValue` is returned)

```
firstRecordDate = context.Datas.Where(x => x.UserID == userId)
                               .Select( x=> x.Time ?? DateTime.MaxValue)
                               .Min();
```

Comment: I don't have any nulls in the table.  Which is why this is kinda driving me crazy lol.

Comment: @Fritos: Is `Time` specified to allow null value though? That could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(DateTime)context.Datas.Where(x => x.UserId != null && x.UserID.Equals(userId)).Min(x => x.Time)
```

The userID != null should evaluate first which will prevent nulls when you get to the Min. I haven't tested that but I think I remember doing stuff like it in the past.

Comment: That only prevents `null`s for `x.UserId`, not `x.Time`.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misread. Either way if you put the != null condition at the beginning of your where clause it should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `Min` function is attempting to return the minimum value, and I've encountered this message before when no elements were being returned from the `IQueryable` - you need to check for the existance of elements before invoking, or declare `firstRecordDate` as a `DateTime?`.

Debugging lambda's is not supported in the watch window. If you want to debug it, I would suggest instead making it a long form lambda over multi line in order to debug

```
.Where(x =>
   {
       return x.ToString();
   });
```

You would be able to debug the inner method code then.

Comment: So I've made firstRecordDate a DateTime?, and I am checking to see if any records are returned (well, I think I am, is it valid to check against a null? [please see code above]), but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: You're still trying to convert a null to `DateTime`. AKA `(DateTime)test.Min(x => x.Time);` should be `(DateTime?)test.Min(x => x.Time);` if anything. In addition, you shouldn't be calling `test != null` but `test.Any()` `test` will never be null, it's always going to be someform of compiler generated `enumerable` call.

Answer (score 1):

You will get that error if context.Datas.Where(x => x.UserID.Equals(userId)) does not return any values.

If you use DateTime? instead of DateTime it will avoid this error by returning null.